# Linux Mint Cinnamon won't boot to GUI, only FreeDOS

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, gui, freedos

Trying to dual-boot Linux with windows 10. I formatted my flash drive with Rufus, then copied the 18.2 64-bit Linux mint Cinnamon file to the root of the drive. When I try to boot from the drive, it opens FreeDOS, and won't boot to the GUI. 
[image: Image for clarity]

Comment: It looks like your copy to the root of the drive was not what you should have been doing. You can try `dir` and see if you see the filename. If you do, you copied the file to the root of the filesystem on your USB drive, instead of replacing the filesystem with the (Mint image) file.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of known issues with Rufus, for more info you can follow this [link](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/185)

Another problem seems to be that you haven't installed a linux iso on your pen-drive (read the link for more info) and because of that you can't run any linux command, because you are on FreeDOS which is kinda MS-DOS system.

You can follo [this](https://itsfoss.com/guide-install-linux-mint-16-dual-boot-windows/) guide to see how to install linux mint.